# How can I specifiy an alternate layout for NotFound.cshml and ErrorPage.cshtml in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I know you can use layout filters for normal pages with urls, but upon errors the view changes while keeping the url the same, so I can't utilize a new layout based on the path. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head:

If you look in Core > Shapes > Views, you will see two files - one called `ErrorPage.cshtml` and one called `NotFound.cshtml`. Simply copy these files and paste them into your theme's view folder.

I have not tested this method with these particular pages, but I did do something similar with the `LogOn` widget.

Something to bear in mind is that the contents of these files will be rendered in the `Content` zone of your current theme.